# How to use bezierPathWithCGPath Swift

Tags: swift, cgpath, nsbezierpath

I need to make a bezier path, I have the CGPath
the only information I found was this:

> Declaration
> SWIFT
>
> ```
> convenience init(CGPath CGPath: CGPath)
> ```

the first is written normal, the second in Italics and the third purple in the developers library

How should I use it? Please give me an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a valid CGPath, just do this:

```
bezier_path = UIBezierPath(CGPath: your_cg_path)
```

The vast majority of the `yWithX` type methods from Objective-C were replaced with init methods in Swift. [This Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html) has more information on the subject.